# Module x has been defined multiple times

Tags: purescript

I have installed some purescript packages using bower and here is my bower.json file.

```
{
  "name": "halogen-cube",
  "ignore": [
      "**/.*",
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "output",
      "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "purescript-prelude": "^3.1.1",
    "purescript-console": "^3.0.0",
    "purescript-halogen": "^2.0.0",
    "purescript-js-timers": "^3.0.0",
    "purescript-halogen-svg": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "purescript-psci-support": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I wanted to add purescript-web-uievents package so I added "purescript-web-uievents" : "^2.0.0" to my bower.json file and installed all packages again.
But after that, when I run building app, I am getting this issue.

```
module Data.Map has been defined multiple times:
```

What should I do to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error is the result of the same module name existing in two different dependencies. This can happen when a module is moved from one package to another.

In the case of `Data.Map`, at one point it was a part of [`purescript-maps`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maps/3.5.0). However, this package is now [deprecated](https://github.com/purescript-deprecated/purescript-maps); and `Data.Map` was moved to [`purescript-ordered-collections`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-ordered-collections).

My guess is that you have one dependency that transitively includes `purescript-maps` while another depends on `purescript-ordered-collections`.